# how can i perform encryption function program by using this prototype function char *encrypt(char *pEncryptedText, const char *pText); in c++

Tags: c++, string, encryption, cryptography

I am starting to study program c++ in school. This is my task that should be manage it. I need some help how I can fix it this task. Thanks for advance

> Write a program that asks for a text and encrypts it by replacing each character with the character placed three steps further on in the alphabet. Use the English alphabet, which
>   consists of the characters 'a' - 'z'. The program should print the encrypted string and the encryption should be placed in a function according to the following function prototype:

```
char *encrypt(char *pEncryptedText, const char *pText);
```

> Here is pText the c-string to be encrypted and pEncryptedText is the string where the encrypted text is saved. As can be seen from the prototype, the original text should be kept unmodified. The return value shall be a pointer to the encrypted text.

I am trying to write program for encryption according instructions above but I could not manage. Please I need help!

```
encrypton = encrypt(EncryptText, pText);
```

**This program is still no finish because it gives me error when it compiled 
this error:**

> Error 4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "char * __cdecl encrypt(char *,char const *)" (?encrypt@@YAPADPADPBD@Z) referenced in function _main

Comment: It would help to see your code, please edit it into the question.

Comment: char *encrypt(char *pEncryptedText, const char *pText);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 
 int count = 0;
 int length;
 char *encrypton;
 //getText(input);
 const char *pText;
 char *EncryptText;
 string text(EncryptText, pText);
 encrypton = encrypt(EncryptText, pText);

Comment: To simply get it to compile, you will need to define the **encrypt** function. To start, _define_ the function by having it **return NULL;**. It won't do anything useful, but it will compile.  See this link for [declaring vs defining in C++](http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html)

Answer (score 2):

It's telling you that the function:

```
char *encrypt(char *pEncryptedText, const char *pText)
```

does not exist. You've declared it, allowing it to compile, but the linking stage is failing because the function is not defined (implemented). I'm guessing that the assignment is for you to implement this function, known as a Caesar Cipher. There are plenty of examples online. Hope this helps!